# DevExpress (JS / HTML) Attach Events to Elements in a Popup

Tags: javascript, html, devexpress, devextreme

How do you properly attach events to elements in a popup?

This is how I currently do it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="userDetail">
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <div id="button-confirm"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var userDetail = $("#userDetail").dxPopup({
    width: '550',
    height: 'auto',
    showTitle: true,
    title: "Setup Import Template",
    visible: false,
    onShown: function () {
        $('#checkbox').one('click', function () {
             $('.template-view').toggle();
        });
        $("#button-confirm").dxButton({
            onClick: function (e) {
                e.jQueryEvent.preventDefault();
                templateDataPopup.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}).dxPopup('instance');
```

The problem with this is that:

- Every time the popup is shown, the jQuery attaches new click event to `#checkbox` element, event after I use `.one()`.
- `#button-confirm` element's click event is NOT being attached twice. This is the behavior I want (although it's not what I expected, I think because it's a DevExpress instance).
- I have tried attached events to elements in the popup before I initialized the popup, but for some reason, after the popup is shown, none of the elements' events work.

So, how do you properly attach events to elements in a popup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from DevExpress support and the suggestion is to use `contentTemplate`. The reply:

> Use the contentTemplate property to create popup content and add the
>   required events to it:

```
contentTemplate: function (contentElement) {
    contentElement.append('<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />');
    var hideButton = $("<div id='button-confirm'>").dxButton({
        text: "Hide popup",
        onClick: function (e) {
            popupInstance.hide();
        }
    });
    contentElement.append(hideButton);
}
```

So, instead of attaching the event through `onShown` event, it's recommended to attach in `contentTemplate`.

You can also load popup content from HTML tag in `contentTemplate`

Comment: You need to accept this/your answer to close/finish this thread.

Comment: @Mikhail, SO only allows accepting own's answers 1 day after posting it.